# Microsoft Word VBA - how to condense fragmented paragraphs that are highlighted?

Tags: vba, ms-word, format

I'm trying to create a macro to find highlighted text with no paragraph integrity in my Word document and remove the linebreaks to condense the text.

For instance, in the image below, I need the macro to convert this:

[image: uncondensed img]

To this:

[image]

I'm fairly new to Word VBA, so I tried my hand at making it.

```
Sub CondenseZap()

'
' CondenseZap Macro
'
'

    Dim rngTemp As Range
 
    Set rngTemp = ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=0, End:=0)
    With rngTemp.Find
     .ClearFormatting
     .Highlight = True
     
     With CondenseRange.Find
            .Text = "^p"
            .Replacement.Text = " "
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        
            .Text = "  "
            .Replacement.Text = " "
            
            While InStr(CondenseRange.Text, "  ")
                .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            Wend
            
            If CondenseRange.Characters.Item(1).Text = " " And _
            CondenseRange.Paragraphs.Item(1).Range.Start = CondenseRange.Start Then _
            CondenseRange.Characters.Item(1).Delete
        End With
        
     End With
     
    End With
      
End Sub
```

This code doesn't execute, and I'm not sure how to write the exit conditions. I tested out and got the program to identify all the words with highlighting, I'm just not sure how to replace the linebreak for each at the end.

**NOTE: I don't want to mess with the linebreak between the other bolded text (BFS '9 shouldn't be merged with "solvency." Only the highlighted parts)**

If someone could help me put this together, I'd really appreciate it.

Cheers.

Comment: easy to go, just play with formatted conditions. See you tomorrow, if no answer to yours.

Comment: Start by recording a macro whilst you use Find and Replace. That will give you the syntax you need to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The code you gave is simply wrong, please correct it！**

The easiest way to compare text is to use highlighting conditions:

```vb
Sub CondenseZap()
   
    Dim rngTemp As Range, ur As UndoRecord
 
    Rem do this, it only takes one step when undo
    Set ur = Word.Application.UndoRecord
    ur.StartCustomRecord "CondenseZap"
    Set rngTemp = ActiveDocument.Range
    
    With rngTemp.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = "^p"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        
        Do While .Execute()
            If rngTemp.Next Is Nothing Then Exit Do
                
            Rem The easiest way to compare text is to use highlighting conditions: 3 = wdTurquoise
            If rngTemp.Previous.HighlightColorIndex = 3 And rngTemp.Next.HighlightColorIndex = 3 Then
                rngTemp.Text = " "
            End If
            
            'reset the range
            rngTemp.SetRange rngTemp.End, rngTemp.Document.Range.End
        Loop
        
    End With

    ur.EndCustomRecord
    
End Sub
```

Is this what you want?