# How to remove line break at the end of each paragraph and then join the paragraphs using VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have the following kind of paragraphs in my Word document:

```
My name
is
John Doe.
```

I would like to remove the line breaks at the end of each line and join the lines to achieve the following:

`My name is John Doe.`

In order to do this, I put together the following VBA code, but it doesn't work. I get a Compile error: Can't find project or library.

```
Sub removelinebreak()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim para As paragraph
    
    Set rng = Selection.Range
    
    ' Loop through each paragraph in the range
    For Each para In rng.Paragraphs
        Debug.Print para.Range.text
        If Right(para.Range.text, 1) = vbCr Or Right(para.Range.text, 1) = vbLf Then
            para.Range.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
            para.Range.MoveStart Unit: wdCharacter , Count:=-1
            para.Range.Delete
        End If
    Next para
End Sub
```

Can you please help on where I am going wrong.

Thanks!

**UPDATE - DIFFERENT APPROACH - USING ARRAYS**

I tried the following approach, but even this does not work.
The output is as follows:

```
My name
 is
 John Doe.
```

It just adds a space before `is` and `John Doe`. It does not remove the line breaks.

```
Sub AddSelectedParagraphsToArray()
    Dim selectedParagraphs() As String ' Declare an array to store the selected paragraphs
    Dim paragraph As paragraph ' Variable to hold each selected paragraph
    Dim i As Long
      
    ' Resize the array to accommodate the selected paragraphs
    ReDim selectedParagraphs(1 To Selection.Range.Paragraphs.Count)
    
    ' Loop through the selected paragraphs and add them to the array
    For i = 1 To Selection.Range.Paragraphs.Count
        Set paragraph = Selection.Range.Paragraphs(i)
        paragraph.Range.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd 'Collapse the range to the last point of the paragraph
        paragraph.Range.MoveEnd Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=-1 ' Select the line break
        'selectedParagraphs(i) = Replace(paragraph.Range.text, vbCrLf, " ")
        selectedParagraphs(i) = paragraph.Range.text
    Next
    
    ' Join the elements of the array back into a single string
    Dim joinedText As String
    joinedText = Join(selectedParagraphs, " ")
    
    ' Display the joined text in a message box
    'MsgBox joinedText
    Selection.Range.text = joinedText
End Sub
```

Based off the help received, the following solutions worked:

**Solution 1 - using the `Left` function**

```
Sub AddSelectedParagraphsToArray()
    Dim selectedParagraphs() As String ' Declare an array to store the selected paragraphs
    Dim paragraph As paragraph ' Variable to hold each selected paragraph
    Dim i As Long
      
    ' Resize the array to accommodate the selected paragraphs
    ReDim selectedParagraphs(1 To Selection.Range.Paragraphs.Count)
    
    ' Loop through the selected paragraphs and add them to the array
    For i = 1 To Selection.Range.Paragraphs.Count
        Set paragraph = Selection.Range.Paragraphs(i)
        selectedParagraphs(i) = VBA.Left(paragraph.Range.text, VBA.Len(paragraph.Range.text) - 1)
    Next
    
    ' Join the elements of the array back into a single string
    Dim joinedText As String
    joinedText = Join(selectedParagraphs, " ")
    
    ' Display the joined text in a message box
    'MsgBox joinedText
    Selection.Range.text = joinedText
End Sub
```

**Solution 2 - using the `Replace` function**

```
Sub ReplaceSelectedRangeWithJoinedText()
    Dim selectedParagraphs() As String ' Declare an array to store the selected paragraphs
    Dim paragraph As paragraph ' Variable to hold each selected paragraph
    Dim i As Long
    
    ' Resize the array to accommodate the selected paragraphs
    ReDim selectedParagraphs(1 To Selection.Range.Paragraphs.Count)

    ' Loop through the selected paragraphs and add them to the array
    For i = 1 To Selection.Range.Paragraphs.Count
        Set paragraph = Selection.Range.Paragraphs(i)
        selectedParagraphs(i) = paragraph.Range.text
    Next
    
    ' Join the elements of the array back into a single string and replace line breaks with spaces
    Dim joinedText As String
    Dim texttoreplace As String
    joinedText = Join(selectedParagraphs, "")
    texttoreplace = Replace(joinedText, vbCr, " ")
    'joinedText = Replace(Join(selectedParagraphs, ""), vbCr, " ")
    
    ' Replace the selected range with the joined text
    Selection.Range.text = texttoreplace
End Sub
```

Comment: "it doesn't work" does not impart any information - what happens? Error message?

Comment: @CHill60 you are right, i missed that part. I have updated my question with the error.

Comment: Why don't you use the [**Find**](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/word.find) object to replace the "^p" with """"? If you want to add another paragraph after the period, you can replace "." with ". ^p" .

Comment: Can't test right now, but when you set paragraph = to a paragraph, you probably can't change the range of the *paragraph( as y ou try to do in the paragraph.range.collapse line. What I would usually do is Dim rng As Range, then Set rng = Selection.Range.Paragraphs(i).Range, then rng.collapse.  NB in your first piece of code, looks like one of the ":=" has been reduced to ":" , likely a tramscription error.

Comment: According to your question you want to remove *line breaks*, but your code only processes paragraphs, which end with a *paragraph mark*. If what you state in your question is correct (a screenshot showing the non-printing characters would be very helpful) then you need to use Find and Replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```vb
para.Range.MoveStart Unit: wdCharacter , Count:=-1
```

Should be :

```vb
para.Range.MoveStart Unit:= wdCharacter , Count:=-1
```

Your code is simply wrong and will clear all contents after execution! Try this code first plz:

```vb
Sub removelinebreak()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim para As Paragraph
    
    Dim ur As UndoRecord
    Set ur = Word.Application.UndoRecord
    ur.StartCustomRecord "removelinebreak"
    
    Set rng = Selection.Range
    
    With rng.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .ClearAllFuzzyOptions
        .Text = vbCr
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Forward = True
        .Execute , , , , , , , , , " ", wdReplaceAll
        .Text = vbLf
        .Execute , , , , , , , , , " ", wdReplaceAll
        .Execute Chr(11), , , , , , , , , " ", wdReplaceAll
        .Execute ". ^p", , , , , , , , , ".^p", wdReplaceAll
        .Execute "  ", , , , , , , , , " ", wdReplaceAll
        .ClearFormatting
        .ClearAllFuzzyOptions
    End With
    ur.EndCustomRecord
'    ' Loop through each paragraph in the range
'    For Each para In rng.Paragraphs
'        Debug.Print para.Range.Text
'        If Right(para.Range.Text, 1) = vbCr Or Right(para.Range.Text, 1) = vbLf Then
'            para.Range.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
'            para.Range.MoveStart Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=-1
'            para.Range.Delete
'        End If
'    Next para
End Sub
```

If this is what you want, you can refer to my previous answers:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76378388/8249058

https://stackoverflow.com/a/76392401/8249058

### UPDATE - DIFFERENT APPROACH - USING ARRAYS

```vb
Sub AddSelectedParagraphsToArray()
    Dim selectedParagraphs() As String ' Declare an array to store the selected paragraphs
    Dim paragraph As paragraph ' Variable to hold each selected paragraph
    Dim i As Long
    
    Dim ur As UndoRecord
    Set ur = Word.Application.UndoRecord
    ur.StartCustomRecord "AddSelectedParagraphsToArray"
      
    ' Resize the array to accommodate the selected paragraphs
    ReDim selectedParagraphs(1 To Selection.Range.Paragraphs.Count)
    
    ' Loop through the selected paragraphs and add them to the array
    For i = 1 To Selection.Range.Paragraphs.Count
        Set paragraph = Selection.Range.Paragraphs(i)
'        paragraph.Range.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd 'Collapse the range to the last point of the paragraph
'        paragraph.Range.MoveEnd Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=-1 ' Select the line break
        'selectedParagraphs(i) = Replace(paragraph.Range.text, vbCrLf, " ")

        rem this is the point!!! the last character is still vbcr (ie. chr(13), "^p", etc.)
        'selectedParagraphs(i) = paragraph.Range.Text
        selectedParagraphs(i) = VBA.Left(paragraph.Range.Text, VBA.Len(paragraph.Range.Text) - 1)
    Next
    
    ' Join the elements of the array back into a single string
    Dim joinedText As String
    joinedText = Join(selectedParagraphs, " ")
    
    ' Display the joined text in a message box
    'MsgBox joinedText
    Selection.Range.Text = joinedText
    
    ur.EndCustomRecord
End Sub
```

Comment: Your correction is incorrect. There should not be a space between `=` and `wdCharacter`, nor should there be a space before the comma. When using functions that have optional parameters, such as `Find.Execute`, it is best practice to use labels to indicate the parameters being used. Using commas to indicate that parameters have been omitted makes your code harder to understand.

Comment: I have tried a different approach. I have updated my question. Can you please shed light on why the different approach is not working. I was hopeful that would.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt Thank you, using the comma expression just shows the other way to implement the code of the method, cause there's already a way existed you mentioned. I think this is a forum for solving programming problems, not just an instructor textbook for beginners. And `Unit:= wdCharacter` is the loss of the "=", not space's problem.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt If you are referring to the space before and after the "=", indeed, however, it will be automatically corrected in the VBE compiler, so it should not be a big problem.

Comment: @Nosail All right, that's it!

Comment: "I think this is a forum for solving programming problems, not just an instructor textbook for beginners." - Whilst that may be true, if you are going to post an answer you should at least first make sure that it is syntactically correct. The reason using commas is considered bad practice is that it makes the code less readable and more difficult to understand, whereas using named parameters makes it truly clear which parameters are being used.

Comment: @OscarSun thank you for refactoring my code that used the arrays approach. I used the `Left` function and it worked. As an alternative, i also used the `Replace` method, and that worked as well. Let me update my question with the solutions.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt Thank you for your attention and suggestions. I also agree. In the future, I will still according to the situation to inter use with these two kinds of writing (because I see most of the ways to implement it using the named parameters way to do, afraid that they are not aware of there are other ways to write it). The code attached to my answer, as long as it can be tested in my environment, is tested by myself with no problem before posting. Please don't worry. I'm grateful. And Thank you.